# Returning multiple resultsets with EntityFramework repository

Tags: entity-framework, repository, multiple-resultsets

I am working on a code where I need Multiple tables as result of a stored procedure. I am using Entity Framework repository pattern. It returns and bind an IEnumerable object, but I need to bind it with multiple IEnumerables at the same time.
Can anybody help?

This is the code I am using : 
db.Database.SqlQuery("procReturnsMultipleResuiltSets")

Comment: have you read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx) ?

Comment: @tschmit007, that's exactly what he needs, you can post the essential part as an answer

Answer (score 1):

the ways to achieve your goal are disclosed in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx).

From related article the most common way is:

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
// If using Code First we need to make sure the model is built before we open the connection 
// This isn't required for models created with the EF Designer 
db.Database.Initialize(force: false); 

// Create a SQL command to execute the sproc 
var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand(); 
cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetAllBlogsAndPosts]"; 

try 
{ 

    db.Database.Connection.Open(); 
    // Run the sproc  
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

    // Read Blogs from the first result set 
    var blogs = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db) 
        .ObjectContext 
        .Translate<Blog>(reader, "Blogs", MergeOption.AppendOnly);    


    foreach (var item in blogs) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name); 
    }         

    // Move to second result set and read Posts 
    reader.NextResult(); 
    var posts = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db) 
        .ObjectContext 
        .Translate<Post>(reader, "Posts", MergeOption.AppendOnly); 


    foreach (var item in posts) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(item.Title); 
    } 
} 
finally 
{ 
    db.Database.Connection.Close(); 
} 
}
```

please note the important remark: **The first result set must be consumed before moving to the next result set**.

Comment: I am using the same but it throws error when I use custom class, which is not a part of my dbSet entity group. I want to create some generic method in my repository for the same.

Comment: This is the error I am getting "The EntitySet name 'AppsLoaderContext.MyClassName' could not be found."

Comment: by using executeReader, the method is taking long time, is there any alternate way to implement multiple result sets?